# Dismiss a View Controller and present a new one in the same method - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

**Summary of problem**

- I have two View Controllers (VC1 = MainViewController and VC2 = ResultViewController).
  In VC1 there is a method called endGame(). In this method I want to both dismiss VC1 and present VC2.
- In VC2 there is a button function called playAgainButton(). In this function I want to both dismiss VC2 and present VC1.
- when I try to first dismiss VC1 and then present VC2, VC1 cannot present VC2 because VC1 is already dismissed and doesn't exist in the stack.

  ```
     dismiss(animated: true) {
       self.present(rvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
  ```
- When I try to first present VC2 and then dismiss VC1, then VC2 appears for a 1 second and then immediately disappears.

  ```
     present(rvc, animated: true) {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
  ```

**What I have tried**

I have come up with similar problems:

- [Dismissing a View Controller and displaying another View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823934/dismissing-a-view-controller-and-displaying-another-view-controller). This has the closest answer to my question. It suggests using protocol. So by using protocol I solved half of the problem --> While in VC2, I can both dismiss VC2 and present VC1. But while in VC1 I cannot both dismiss VC1 and present VC2.

I use the latest swift and Xcode version.

**My code**

**VC1**

```
  // protocol for presenting View Controllers
  protocol VcDelegate: AnyObject {
    func presentVc(vc: UIViewController)
  }

  // The main view controller of the game.
  class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
  UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, VcDelegate {

  // MARK: - Protocol functions & properties
  func presentVc(vc: UIViewController) {
    present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
  // instance of VcDelegate protocol
  weak var mvcDelegate: VcDelegate?

  // MARK: - Properties
  // the level of the game
  var level: Int = 0
  // the player's score
  var score: Int = 0

  /// Terminate the game for the next level and show results page
  private func gameOver() {
    // present the resultViewController
    if let rvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultViewController")   as? ResultViewController {
      rvc.resultLevel = level
      rvc.resultScore = score
      rvc.rvcDelegate = self
  
      // dismiss MainViewController
      dismiss(animated: true) {
        // present ResultViewController by using instance of VcDelegate protocol
        self.mvcDelegate?.presentVc(vc: rvc)
      }
     }
   }
  }
```

**VC2**

```
// This page is viewed after a level is finished. It shows level results and play again  button.
class ResultViewController: UIViewController, VcDelegate {

  // MARK: - Protocol functions & properties
  func presentVc(vc: UIViewController) {
    present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
  weak var rvcDelegate: VcDelegate?

  // MARK: - Properties

  // variable showing game level
  var resultLevel = 0
  // variable showing current score
  var resultScore = 0

  /// When play again button is tapped a new game starts (a new mainViewController is presented)
  @IBAction func playAgainButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // present a new MainViewController
    if let mvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController {
      mvc.level = resultLevel
      mvc.score = resultScore
      mvc.mvcDelegate = self
  
      // dismiss ResultViewController
      dismiss(animated: true) { 
        // present MainViewController by using instance of VcDelegate protocol
        self.rvcDelegate?.presentVc(vc: mvc)
      }
    }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create the `VC1` and you pass `self` as `mvcDelegate`, you actually passing `VC2` which is about to be dismissed and after the dismiss `VC2` cannot present any view controller.

You probably need to pass the delegate of the one view controller to the other before you present it:

```
// Pass your delegate to the other view controller delegate
mvc.mvcDelegate = rvcDelegate
// dismiss ResultViewController
dismiss(animated: true) {
    // present MainViewController by using instance of VcDelegate protocol
    self.rvcDelegate?.presentVc(vc: mvc)
}
```

And the other way around:

```
// Pass your delegate to the other view controller delegate
rvc.rvcDelegate = mvcDelegate
// dismiss MainViewController
dismiss(animated: true) {
    // present ResultViewController by using instance of VcDelegate protocol
    self.mvcDelegate?.presentVc(vc: rvc)
}
```

As mentioned in the comments VC1 is the `rootViewController` of the application window. So, to achieve what you are looking for, you need to replace the `rootViewController`.

In MainViewController:

```
// Change rootViewController of the view's window with ResultViewController
view.window?.rootViewController = rvc
```

And the same in ResultViewController:

```
// Change rootViewController of the view's window with MainViewController
view.window?.rootViewController = mvc
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is not working. VC1 is dismissed but it still doesn't present VC2

Comment: @JaidenRyder when you are initially present VC1 do you set it's `mvcDelegate` property? The important thing here is that none of the 2 view controllers can present each other. Because both will be dismissed.

Comment: in fact the app starts with VC1. And I set mvcDelegate property only in endGame() method. And I do exactly the same thing in both view controllers. In VC2 I can dismiss and present VC1 in the same method, but I can't do the same when I am in VC1. When I am in VC1 I can dismiss VC1, I can present VC2. But 'self.mvcDelegate?.presentVc(vc: rvc)' code doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JaidenRyder so, VC1 is not presented, is the `rootViewController` of your application Window. That changes a thing or two.

Comment: @JaidenRyder Happy to help. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)